# Como referenciar chaves estrangeiras em formulários de cadastro?

Tags: php, mysql, chave-estrangeira, inserir

Estou fazendo um site de uma biblioteca como trabalho do colégio, que possui a seguinte tabela no banco de dados:

[image: 1]

Meu problema é que eu não sei como tratar o código php e o formulário dos campos que recebem chaves estrangeiras.

Por ex.: No cadastro de empréstimo eu preciso referenciar o livro que está sendo emprestado e para isso tenho a chave estrangeira 'manterlivros_codigolivros', porém não sei como fazer o código que possibilitaria o funcionaria realizar essa função corretamente na tela de cadastro.

Se for de utilidade, os códigos para cadastro que utilizei nas outras tabelas que não possuem chaves estrangeiras seguem esse formato:

```php
<?php
    require_once ("InscricaoClass.php");

    $user = livros::getInstance();

    if (isset($_GET['codigolivros'])) {
        $codigolivros=$_GET['codigolivros'];
        $user->__set('codigolivros', $codigolivros);
        $user->carregar();
    } else {
        $codigolivros=0;
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $user ->__set('titulo', $_POST['titulo']);
        $user ->__set('editora', $_POST['editora']);
        $user ->__set('autor', $_POST['autor']);
        $user ->__set('genero', $_POST['genero']);

        if ($_POST ['codigolivros']>0) {
            $user-> alterar();
        } else {
            $user->gravar();
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cadastro Livros</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <h2> Cadastro Livros</h2>

            <label>Código</label>
            Código:
            <input type="number" name="codigolivros"  value="<?php echo $codigolivros;?>" >
            <br><br><br>

            Titulo: <br>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" value="<?php echo $user::$titulo;?>" placeholder=""> 
            <br><br><br>

            Editora: <br>
            <input type="text" name="editora" value="<?php echo $user::$editora;?>" placeholder=""> 
            <br><br><br>

            Autor: <br>
            <input type="text" name="autor" value="<?php echo $user::$autor;?>" placeholder=""> 
            <br><br><br>

            Genero: <br>
            <input type="text" name="genero" value="<?php echo $user::$genero;?>" placeholder=""> 
            <br><br> 

            <input type="submit" name="" value="Gravar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

O código acima necessita desse:

```php
    <?php

class livros
{
    //inicio dos atributos
    public static $codigolivros;
    public static $titulo;
    public static $editora;
    public static $autor;
    public static $genero;  

    public static $instance;

    //inicio dos métodos
    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once("Conexao.php");
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        self::$instance = new livros ();
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __set($var,$val)
    {
        $this->$var = $val;
    }

    public function __get($var)
    {
        $this->$var;
    }
    //Fim dos métodos padrões

    public function gravar()
    {
        try {
            $sql="insert into manterlivros (titulo, editora, autor, genero) values (:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4)";
            $con=Conexao::getInstance () ->prepare($sql);
            $con->bindValue (":p1", $this->titulo);
            $con->bindValue (":p2", $this->editora);
            $con->bindValue (":p3", $this->autor);
            $con->bindValue (":p4", $this->genero);
            $result=$con->execute();

            return $result;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "ERRO".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function consultar()
    {
        try {
            $sql ="select * from manterlivros";
            $con= conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
            $con -> execute ();

            return $con;
        } catch (Expection $e) {
            echo "ERRO NO CONSULTAR";
        }
    }


    public function excluir($codigo)
    {
        try {
            $sql = "delete from manterlivros where codigolivros = '".$codigo."'" ;
            $con = Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);

            return $con->execute();echo "excluindo";
        } catch (exception $e) {
            echo "ERRO NO EXCLUIR";
        }
    }

    public function alterar()
    {
        try {
            $sql="update manterlivros set titulo=:p1, editora=:p2, autor=:p3, genero=:p4 where codigolivros=:p0";

            $con=Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
            $con->bindValue (":p1", $this->titulo);
            $con->bindValue (":p2", $this->editora);
            $con->bindValue (":p3", $this->autor);
            $con->bindValue (":p4", $this->genero);
            $con->bindValue ("p0", $this->codigolivros);

            $result=$con->execute();

            return $result;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Erro no Alterar";
        }
    }


    public function carregar()
    {
        try { 

            $sql ="select * from manterlivros where codigolivros=:p1";

            $con= Conexao::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
            $con->bindValue (":p1", $this->codigolivros);
            $con->execute ();

            foreach ($con as $linha) {
                $this::$titulo = $linha['titulo'];
                $this::$editora = $linha['editora'];
                $this::$autor = $linha['autor'];
                $this::$genero = $linha['genero'];
            }

            return $con;
        } catch (Expection $e) {
            echo "ERRO NO ALTERAR";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A 'regra' da chave estrangeira é, tenha como exemplo produto e categoria. Ao cadastrar um produto deve existir uma categoria caso seja cadastrado um valor que não existe na tabela categoria, o insert na tabela de produtos vai falhar. Edite a pergunta especifique melhor o seu problema/dúvida.

Comment: Editei, espero que assim fique mais claro.

Answer (score 0):

**Versão mais completa:**

Seu formulario deve ser montado com pelo menos essas informações, uma caixa de texto para o nome, após digitado o nome é feita uma requisição ajax para o PHP buscar a matricula baseado no nome, feito o campo matricula é preenchido.

Agora faça um botão que abre um modal para adicionar os livros para emprestimo. Ao clicar em gravar os principais dados recebidos devem ser, `matricula` e `livros`(que um array e contém o `id_livro` e outros dados).

Essas informações devem ser gravadas em tabela `emprestimos` os principais campos são `matricula`, `id_livro`, `data_emprestimo`, `data_devolucao`.

**Versão simples(só para exemplo mesmo)**

Crie um único form com os campos `matricula`, e por exemplo 3 ou limite de emprestimos por aluno combobox o name dele deve ficar entre colchetes, assim: `<select name="livros[]">`, para gravar veja o paragrafo anterior, será necessário foreach para registrar todos os emprestimos, lembre também que as vezes apens um livro pode ser emprestado.

Comment: Eu consegui superficialmente entender o que você disse, porém eu não sei como fazer o código pra realizar essas funções. Se você tivesse como, poderia passar uma sintaxe simples pra eu tentar entender em uso?

Answer (score 0):

Na sua classe Livros() crie um método para consultar o ID do livro digitado no campo `name="codigolivros"` assim voce vai obter a FK para gravar.